# Virtuoso Upgrade

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-server, virtuoso

I have a Virtuoso version 06.01.3127 installed on Ubuntu 14.04.05 LTS version (Ubuntu-server).

I would like to upgrade my Virtuoso to at least version 7.2.4.2+, which includes the GeoSpatial features that I need.

I have looked the info provided in the following link [Virtuoso: Upgrading from Release 6.x to Release 7.x](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/UpgradingToVOS610#Upgrading%20from%20Release%206.x%20to%20Release%207.x) but I have not been able to follow these steps.

To start with, the second step "*Check the size of the .trx file, typically found alongside the .db and .ini files*".
I can only find the `odbc.ini` and `virtuoso.ini` files, which are inside `/virtuoso-opensource-6.1` folder.

Am I looking in the wrong place?

Does anyone have any guidance in this matter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide more detail of how you "have not been able to follow these steps". The web page you linked is our best guidance at present, but improvement is always possible. Specific questions, error messages, etc., will all help us help you.

Comment: I just added the details of my problems. Basically, I cannot access to the files which are specified in the second step of the tutorial

Comment: I would think that the `.trx` file not being there counts as "zero bytes" and you should proceed to step 3.

Comment: I see @mkrieger1 . How could I `(...) install the newer v7.x binary components, either atop or after removing the older v6.x binary components.` ??

Comment: @Havor I don't know. I have never used that software, I only looked at the instructions you have linked.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/) (producer of [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), employer of me) does not force the location of *any* file -- so we cannot tell you exactly where to look on your host.

`virtuoso.db` is the default database storage file; your local file might be any `*.db`.  This file must be present in a mounted filesystem, and should be fully identified (with full filepath) within the active `*.ini` file (default being `virtuoso.ini`).

You might have multiple `virtuoso.ini` and/or `virtuoso.db` files in different locations in your filesystem.  You might try using some Linux commands, like --

```
find / -name virtuoso.db -ls
find / -name virtuoso.ini -ls
find / -name '*.db' -ls
find / -name '*.ini' -ls
```

Installing the binary components is done by following the [instructions for installation](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/#How%20Do%20I%20Install%20Virtuoso?)...

You can get advice from a lot of experienced Virtuoso Users on [the mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/)...